# Loop through UIImageViews - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, uiimageview

I have some `UIImageView`s in an array and want to loop through them to set an image, but I don't know how.

If I have one ImageView, `imgv`, then I do this:

```
self.imgv.image =
```

But how do I behave with many UIImageViews in a loop? I can't do the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [imageViewArray count]; i++)
{
  self.i.image =
}
```

Comment: add your imageview to nsarry and iterate through that array and set the image all imageview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use the index in the loop to get an item out of the array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < [imageViewArray count]; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = imageViewArray[i];
    imageView.image = ...;
}
```

or, you use a `for in` loop:

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in imageViewArray) 
{
    imageView.image = ...;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int i = 0; i < [imageViewArray count]; i++)
{
   UIImageView *tempImageView = [imageViewArray objectAtIndex:i];
   tempImageView.image=image;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < [imageViewArray count]; i++)
{
  [imageViewArray[i] setImage:image];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set same image to all image views in the array then simply use,

```
[imageViewArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setImage:) withObject:image];
```

If you need to set different images then you have to loop through the array like most of the answer have mentioned.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(UIImageView *imgVw in imageViewArray)
{
    imgVw.image = ...;
}
```

**for - in** is used to iterate through all the element of an array.

Comment: This is a little confused. `imgVw` should be used to set the images on, not set as the image on an invalid reference...

Comment: Edited my answer chek nw